# Change value on time PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, time

I have this code which change value on click

```
$.post('test.php', {val:value}, function (data) {
var value = document.getElementById('value');
val.value = value;
}
```

I need to change value on time(for example on 10 sec) how i can do that with Ajax?

Comment: Every 10 seconds or after a 10 second delay? Either way you are going to want to use `setTimeout(fn, timeInMiliSeconds)`

Comment: after 10 second delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to call the server (i.e. "poll") and get the latest value based on a set time interval. If that is the case, you should look at the `setInterval()` function and have it call your update method. For example:

```
function update() {
   $.post('test.php', {val:value}, function (data) {
       var value = document.getElementById('value');
       val.value = value;
   }
}

// Call every 10 seconds
var seconds = 10;
var int = setInterval(update, seconds * 1000);
```

Be aware that this sort of polling, especially on Apache (my guess since you tagged PHP) can quickly use up your max connections if you have a lot of traffic and effectively DDOS your own web server.

Comment: This is very good answer. But im making some quiz app, and im doing in ajax because i have database with questions and aswers. i have two php files which im combinating for changing questions (im done with that changing question when user click on some answer). So i want to use this setInterval() function to change question after 10 sec delay and  decrement one php variable for -1

Answer (score 0):

So since you said after 10 seconds:

You want to use the setTimeout function, after the delay specified in miliseconds

```
function postValue() {
   $.post('test.php', {val:value}, function (data) {
       var value = document.getElementById('value');
       val.value = value;
   }
}
```

Now we set the click handler to call the postValue function after a timeout of 10 seconds

```
var seconds = 10;
$('#button').click(function(){
    setTimeout(postValue, seconds * 1000)
});
```

Comment: Not on click... automatic. So i need just to define fucntion of $.post , and to use that function in setTimeout... right?

Comment: set timeout will only make the post fire once after 10 second and then never again. Use set interval if you want the event to happen every 10 seconds.  Do you have a `gotoNextQuestion()` function (or something similar)